# PowerShell and Regex frustration

Tags: powershell

Ok, so I have a file called functions.ps1 that contains only function code: something like this:

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function1
##  PURPOSE........:  
##  EXAMPLE........:  
##  REQUIREMENTS...:  PowerShell 2.0
##  NOTES..........:  
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Some-Function1
{
Code goes here
}
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function2
##  PURPOSE........:  
##  EXAMPLE........:  
##  REQUIREMENTS...:  PowerShell 2.0
##  NOTES..........:  
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Some-Function2
{
Code goes here
}
```

Now, the last function in this file (and the one relevant to my issue) is this:

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  List-Functions
##  PURPOSE........:  
##  EXAMPLE........:  
##  REQUIREMENTS...:  PowerShell 2.0
##  NOTES..........:  
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function List-Functions
{
    $func_1 = "##  FUNCTION"
    $func_2 = Get-Content \\Server\scripts\functions.ps1
    $func_2 | select-string -pattern $func_1 | foreach {write-host $_.line}
}
```

The idea here is that from the console I can dot source the function.ps1 file, and by firing off List-Functions, I'll get a list of all the functions in the functions file.

Except when run, List-Function returns something like this:

```
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function1
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function2
##  FUNCTION.......:  List-Functions
$func_1 = "##  FUNCTION"
```

Everything is cool, except that last bit of code. I know that it's only matching the pattern I've given it, but it's annoying me something furious.

I know my Regex-fu is weak, and I tried altering List-Functions to filter that bit out, but I am having no joy. Can anyone point out what I can do to get this working correctly?

My solution (which is ugly), was to change List-Functions to this:

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  List-Functions
##  PURPOSE........:  
##  EXAMPLE........:  
##  REQUIREMENTS...:  PowerShell 2.0
##  NOTES..........:  
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function List-Functions
{
    $char = [char] '#'
    $func_1 = $char + $char + "  FUNCTION"
    $func_2 = Get-Content \\server\scripts\functions.ps1
    $func_2 | select-string -pattern $func_1 | foreach {write-host $_.line}
}
```

I told you it was ugly, but it works ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match only lines that begins with the string `##`. So change your regex to

```
$func_1 = "^##  FUNCTION"
```

*Better solution*: Consider using modules. Store your functions `Some-Function1` and `Some-Function2` to file `MyModule.psm1`. Then:

```
PS> Import-Module d:\MyModule.psm1
# or with -DisableNameChecking to suppres warning messages
PS> Import-Module d:\MyModule.psm1 -DisableNameChecking

PS> Get-Command -module MyModule | Select -expand Name
Some-Function1
Some-Function2
```

---

*How you can try the regex:*

```
@'
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function1
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Some-Function1
{
Code goes here
}
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  some-Function2
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Some-Function2
{
Code goes here
}
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  List-Functions
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function List-Functions
{
    Get-Content d:\temp\sotest.ps1 | 
        select-string -pattern "^##  FUNCTION" | 
        Select -exp Line
}
'@ | Set-Content d:\temp\sotest.ps1
. d:\temp\sotest.ps1
List-Functions
```

Comment: And you can filter the commands output by `Get-Command` via the `CommandType` parameter (alias `Type`) e.g. `gcm -m MyModule -type function`.

Comment: @stej
This is initially what I tried, it is not working. I thought it was just me, good to know that I can at least use an anchor character in POSH regex correctly!

Comment: When I run it with the carat, it get nothing returned at the console. There is something that POSH doesn't like about that regex syntax...

Comment: Ah, my bad. In the actual functions.ps1 file, there is whitespace before the ##, so of course it wasn't the regex syntax, it was me forgetting that I'd need to include the whitespace in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it clarified why it wasn't working the way I had it.

Comment: yeah and I may go that route eventually. Keeping things simple while learning. I've been scripting on Windows for 10+ years, but Scripting with PowerShell is more like programming, and I'm fairly new to some of the concepts.